# Equal box-shadow on top and bottom and equal on right and left

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
    background: red;
    width: 450px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 20px;
    border: 25px solid;
    border-color: blue grey yellow green;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 0 10px purple, 20px -20px 0 10px purple
}
.container-text {
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
}
```

I tried the `outline` property but it remains the same on all sides of a box.So, I'm using `box-shadow`. I'm trying to recreate [this style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD81e.png). But with my code above, I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bPOu.png). I can't seem to figure out how would I get equal solid box-shadow on top-bottom and on right-left. Need some help here.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `spread` value in the `box-shadow` property.

Try this `box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px purple;`